# Mounting Folders in Docker: Windows Host, Windows Image

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

How to use the docker mount option to share a local folder in Docker Container? Currently, I am using this command but I am not being successful.

```
docker run --mount source='c:\temp',target='c:\temp' -i newname:latest
```

I get this error -

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid volume name.
```

My environment: 
Host: Windows Server, version 1709
Docker Container: Windows Server Core, v1709

Comment: Have you tried -v rather than mount? docker run -v 'c:\temp':'c:\temp' -i newname:latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `bind` mount. Example below maps your `host` directory `c:\users\public\` to the one which is inside container `c:\users\public` and then outputs content of that directory.

```html
PS C:\Users\gsuvalia> docker run --rm --mount type=bind,source=c:\users\public\,destination=c:\users\public\ microsoft/nanoserver powershell get-childitem c:\users\public


    Directory: C:\users\public


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-r---        12/1/2017  10:16 PM                Documents
d-r---        7/16/2016   6:47 AM                Downloads
d-r---        7/16/2016   6:47 AM                Music
d-r---        12/1/2017  10:16 PM                Pictures
d-----        8/22/2017  10:26 PM                Roaming
d-r---        7/16/2016   6:47 AM                Videos
```

Comment: This approach worked. I also learned that it's not necessary for the directory to exist beforehand https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes